# Give BehaviorSubject initial value - value being an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I know that I cannot give `BehaviorSubject` an Observable value, but I need a way to solve this issue. On app initialization I am fetching current user (if exists), and I need to give the `BehaviorSubject` that potential value. So my service code looks like this:

```ts
private user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(this.getUser());
public user$ = this.user.asObservable();

getUser(): User {
  // does obviously not work!
  return this.apiService.getUser()
    .map(data => {
      if(data) {
        return data;
      }
      // do something else
    })  
}
```

So is there some magical rxjs operator to solve this issue, or some other possibility?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the return type of the getUser method in the api service?

Comment: Assuming that getUser will return an Observable<User>, you are AFAIK obligated to subscribe somewhere in your code (most likely constructor method) to give that  BehaviorSubject an "initial value" (the value wont be available at the instantiation moment, will be passed by "next" call). So basically that getUser(): User method is impossible to implement.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Not quite obligated: Can be achieved by concatenating observables. Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like

```ts
private user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
public user$ = this.user.asObservable();

constructor() {
  this.getUser();
}

getUser(): User {
  // does obviously not work!
  return this.apiService.getUser()
    .subscribe(data => {
      if(!!data) {
        this.user.next(data); // <<== added
      }
      // do something else
    })  
}
```

Comment: @Jota.Toledo thanks for the update, but I think `do()` also won't cause the observable to do anything. I changed it to `subscribe()`.

Comment: yup, just wanted to point that out. I guess the getUser returns an observable, so in this case you need to modify your answer still: you are returning a subscription,not an User instance

Comment: Could also add .filter(v => !!v) if you don’t want the initial null value to go through, depends on the case though.

Comment: @bryan60 could use a `ReplaySubject` instead of a `BehaviourSubject` for that matter....

Comment: The return value isn't used at all. The `next()` is the relevant part

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will get back to you ASAP! :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've seen examples where they call getUser in the component on ngOnInit method. What is a better approach? In the consturctor of the service or in ngOnInit of the component using it?

Comment: If it depends on a value passed to an input, then you need `ngOnInit`, otherwise I don't see any advantage/disadvantage. It might be easier to unit-test if you keep code out of the constructor. It's mostly personal preference.

Comment: If it depends on a value passed to an input, then you need `ngOnInit`, otherwise I don't see any advantage/disadvantage. It might be easier to unit-test if you keep code out of the constructor. It's mostly personal preference.

Answer (score -1):

What if you do something like

```
private user = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
public user$ = this.getUser()
    .first()
    .concat(this.user.asObservable());

getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.apiService.getUser()
        .map(data => {
            if(data) {
                return data;
            }
            // do something else
        });
}
```

What this does is just conctenating an observable that returns the first user with the subject so you can push updates. This way you don't need to call `.subscribe` anywhere

If you don't want to get `this.getUser()` called for each new subscriber to `user` Subject, you can always use `this.getUser().publish()` stream instead, so it gets shared between new subscribers.

Comment: Ill take a look later. Could you create a plnkr or fiddle to test this?

Comment: This won’t work, it will run the api call on every subscription, which isn’t the goal. You’d need a second subject and a store pattern to make this work the way you intend

Comment: Where do you push values to the subject?

Comment: I'm not pushing, OP does need that to be a subject, I guess that's because he wants to push. Else why bother creating a subject when you can instead just `const user$ = this.getUser()`?

Comment: OP Says "I need to initialize a Subject with something that comes from an observable". This is the way to do it. @Jota.Toledo plunkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/chVpEzUfm5uRZ13j

Comment: @bryan60 That depends on use case, but you can always `.publish()` the observable so it gets shared between subscribers

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will get back to you ASAP! :)

Answer (score -1):

Here’s one way of accomplishing this:

```
private user = new BehaviorSubject(null);
user$ = this.user.switchMap(u => (!!u) 
                                    ? Observable.of(u) 
                                    : this.getUser()
                                          .do(nu =>  if (!!nu) this.user.next(nu))
                                          .switchMap(v => (!v) 
                                                          ? Observable.of(v) 
                                                            : Observable.empty()));
```

This will rerun the api call so long as user has a falsey value.

Comment: the problem that I see with this is that the first observer that starts to get values from "user$" wont get notified when new values are pushed into "user", as it will be taking values from this.getUser() reference

Comment: Not true, the nature of switchMap, it switches when new values come through and cancels previous inner observables. One cool thing about this pattern is that you can cause server refreshes by passing null values through the source, due to the switching.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo FYI, your edit created an infinite loop, the way I had it is correct.

Comment: Actually, no not an infinite loop, just an odd double subscription, but I believe the way I have it is semantically cleaner.

Comment: I really don't think this is semantically cleaner... You have at least 2 side effects in a single line. Consider this, for instance, on the first loop, `u = null`, will get through `this.getUser()`. But this `getUser()` after the `do()` will yield one user that will be yielded to `user$` because of `switchMap`. But inside `do()` you also call `.next(nu)`, which will cause `user$` to yield an extra user for the same one. If it's not like that, then I don't consider this semantically correct either - it's really complex to understand what's going on in there.

Comment: it's one side effect done intentionally, the way this actually plays outin practice is that the subscriber never gets the result of the getUser() call, because the next operation immediately cancels that subscription in the same thread and just reverts to the value that got passed through the source in the do operation, so the subscriber will only actually see one event as intended.  It's a little complicated, but I actually think it's clear, subsscribe to the source, if it doesn't have a value, switch to this remote fetch method and save the value.

Comment: it's essentially the classic cache get and set scheme in observable format.

Comment: @bryan60 Well, in plunkr doesn't seem to work https://next.plnkr.co/edit/7ynJ7opLCQjqB3Gk (has the exact behaviour I described: duplicated initial value). With all respects, if you're not too sure why does this doesn't work, I wouldn't call this solution "semantically correct". It's far from it.

Comment: And another issue, what if you call `.next(null)` on purpose to set the user to null? This would refetch the user (and again, yield it twice in the result stream)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159509/discussion-between-olivarra1-and-bryan60).

Comment: Good point, this is still recoverable though, and it isn't necesarily bad if events trigger twice, depends on the case. and doens't have the drawback of repeating the API call on subsequent subscriptions, see my update.

Comment: causing the user to refresh by setting it to null is a feature, not a bug

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will get back to you ASAP! :)